# How to squash duplicate commits due to an incorrect rebase?

Tags: git, branch, rebase, pull-request, squash

I have a kinda specific, complex Git situation due to mistakes I made early on and didn't address at that time. I'll first explain the steps I took (with Git network visuals) to get to where I am.

1. I started with an initial `master` branch.

[image: step-1]

2. I created a `new-catalog` branch and made set of commits `A`.

[image: step-2]

3. I rebased `new-catalog` with outdated local `master` and pulled into the new rebased `new-catalog` branch. (Although I didn't know it at the time, this would be the start of my misery)

[image: step-3]

This created a second set of commits `A'` identical to `A` but with different commits with new timestamps.

[image: step-3-context]

4. I created a `beta/master` branch (still off the outdated local `master`), and PRed `new-catalog` into `beta/master`.

[image: step-4]

5. I made another set of commits `B` on `beta/master`.

[image: step-5]

6. I made a sub branch `beta/bootstrap` off of `beta/master`.

[image: step-6]

Now, that I am here, I want to rebase `beta/master` with `master` to prepare to PR back into `master`. I did try rebasing, however, I am getting some weird conflicts that I suspect is due to the duplicate set of commits `A` and `A'`. What is the safest way to rebase `beta/master` with `master`?

I have considered doing an interactive rebase and squashing/dropping the initial set of commits `A`, but I also don't want to lose the time information of those commits. If this is the best option, I am willing to lose the time information, but I just wanted to see if there was a better way.

In addition, if I am able to rebase `beta/master` successfully, do I need to rebase `beta/bootstrap` as well? Or will I just be able to PR into `beta/master` without any conflicts?

I made a [git-practice repository](https://github.com/itsjoshthedeveloper/git-practice) to recreate these mistakes and [this](https://github.com/itsjoshthedeveloper/git-practice/network) is the whole network.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi! I thing you can create new branch from point you want to start. Then make `git cherry-pick` to select commit you want to presere. When new branch with changes will be ready you can `git reset` your broken branch to the point you want. Then you can marge your change.

Comment: Watch out: the "network graphs" you've posted appear to be GitHub's network graphs, which are not commit graphs and are sometimes entirely wrong. (For this reason, I never use them.) Fortunately you have an actual repository that one can clone; that's probably a better place to look into answering this question.

Comment: @k.nieszporek Sorry I don't think I understand, could you explain in more detail?

Comment: @torek can you explain how GitHub's network graphs differ from commit graphs?

Comment: I can't *explain* GitHub's network graphs at all because they're sometimes full of nonsense. But it's clear what they are *aiming* for: they want to correlate activity in different, but related, Git repositories (GitHub "forks"). This job is nearly impossible so the nonsense is quite forgivable. It's hard enough to draw an accurate graph of what's in a single repository, with branch names that can't be inconsistent.

Comment: I cloned your repo, but I think the problem and solution are on your local repo. I think, the firstmaybe mistake was you rebase on the old local master. And maybe you can try to fix it simpler. Did you check what 'git reflog' do? When you combine the result with 'git reset' you can fix almost everything in git (i think:)) You can reset your new-catalog branch to the state before you rebase it onto the "deprecated" master. Then you can do rebase it again on the updated master in a clean way. Should be simpler than 'cherry-pick'

Comment: @k.nieszporek the problem with that method is I would lose all the commits I had made since I had incorrectly rebased it onto the deprecated master. I am looking for a way to save the sets of commits `A`/`A'` and `B`

Comment: No you won't missed this commit. You will reset  to the state where this commits exist. This is the new-catalog branch just before rebase (you have your changes, but you did not rebase it on outage master yet). I don't know how to explain it. Read this chapter, maybe it will help you. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the safest way to rebase `beta/master` with `master`?

I found that doing an interactive rebase and dropping the initial set of commits `A` is a safe way to simplify everything. And contrary to what I thought before, rebasing preserves the author timestamps (as seen when using `git log`) and only replaces the commit timesteps (as seen in GitHub).

#### How to rebase `beta/master` on `master`

1. `git checkout beta/master`

   Checkout the `beta/master` branch.
2. `git rebase -i master`

   Interactively rebase `beta/master` on `master`.
3. Drop the original set of commits `A`

   Replace `pick` with `d` in the text editor for each of the commits in the original set `A`. For my `git-practice` repo, this would be commits `3e8c537`, `642dc34`, `7e2fa44`, and `b40f340`.

   Then, save and quit the editor.
4. Handle any merge conflicts

   Git will then compare each commit in `beta/master` (starting from the bottom of the branch/deepest parent commit) to the HEAD of `master`.

   If you encounter any merge conflicts, the top change will be the current code in the HEAD of the `master` branch (branch you're rebasing into) and the bottom change will be the code corresponding to that commit whose changes conflicted with HEAD. You can choose the top change, bottom change, both, or neither.

   After you get the file to how you want it, make sure to save the file and `git add` it to stage the changes. Then, `git rebase --continue` to continue.

   If you merge all the conflicts, it should rebase successfully and show `Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/beta/master.`
5. `git push --force origin beta/master`

   This will push your local `beta/master` and override your remote `origin/beta/master`.

> Do I need to rebase `beta/bootstrap` as well? Or will I just be able to PR into `beta/master` without any conflicts?

You can PR (merge commit) into `beta/master`, but rebasing would clean up the commit history a lot.

#### How to rebase `beta/bootstrap` on `beta/master`

1. `git checkout beta/bootstrap`

   Checkout the `beta/bootstrap` branch.
2. `git rebase --onto beta/master beta/master@{1} beta/bootstrap`

   Rebase `beta/bootstrap` on `beta/master`.
3. `git push --force origin beta/bootstrap`

   This will push your local `beta/bootstrap` and override your remote `origin/beta/bootstrap`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if i understand all correctly. But I tried reproduce the problem locally and fixing it. I used your git-practis repo.

I reset local master branch to commit fb90356 (I simulate outage master) and create 'new-catalog-demo' branch.

Here is how it looks after two changes

```
[u@d git-practice]$ git reset --hard fb90356
HEAD wskazuje teraz fb90356 Add JavaScript
[u@d git-practice]$ git log -1
fb90356 Add JavaScript
[u@d git-practice]$ git checkout -b new-catalog-demo
Przełączono na nową gałąź „new-catalog-demo”
[u@d git-practice]$ git commit -a -m"Add feature 1"
[new-catalog-demo 5c91e3d] Add feature 1
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
[u@d git-practice]$ git commit -a -m"Add feature 2"
[new-catalog-demo ed804d5] Add feature 2
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+)
[u@d git-practice]$ git log --oneline --graph 
* ed804d5 (HEAD -> new-catalog-demo) Add feature 2
* 5c91e3d Add feature 1
* fb90356 (master) Add JavaScript
* a0f3d5a Add another main feature
```

Then i did reabase onto outage master and pull from origin/master. Here is how it looks after that. In a meantime i reset master to another commit to simulate some changes from another side. In the second log we can see A', B' commits.

```
[u@d git-practice]$ git rebase master 
Pomyślnie przestawiono i zaktualizowano refs/heads/new-catalog-demo.
[u@d git-practice]$ git log --oneline --graph 
* c3f9338 (HEAD -> new-catalog-demo) Add feature 2
* 5ddb34c Add feature 1
* b89ef1b (master) Change another feature
* e7278df Change a main feature
* fb90356 Add JavaScript
* a0f3d5a Add another main feature
* 5a7b447 Add main feature
[u@d git-practice]$ git pull origin master
[u@d git-practice]$ git log --oneline --graph 
*   3b9619e (HEAD -> new-catalog-demo) Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/itsjoshthedeveloper/git-practice into new-catalog-demo
|\  
| * b4bf1c6 (origin/master, origin/HEAD) Update main feature
| * f716c02 Change another main feature #-->> B' ??
| * f4f9669 Change main feature         #-->> A' ??
| * 98acbf4 Reset changed features
* | c3f9338 Add feature 2
* | 5ddb34c Add feature 1
|/  
* b89ef1b (master) Change another feature
* e7278df Change a main feature
* fb90356 Add JavaScript
* a0f3d5a Add another main feature
* 5a7b447 Add main feature
* ec699c4 Update README
* 395a5c6 Add h1
* e1633b3 Add index.html
* f11b51f Initial commit
```

I suppose i reproduce your problem. Here is how i fixed it

First we must check `git reflog` to find the place, where we have `new-catalog-demo` branch with changes before inappropriate rebase.

```
[u@d git-practice]$ git reflog 
3b9619e (HEAD -> new-catalog-demo) HEAD@{0}: pull origin master: Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
c3f9338 HEAD@{1}: rebase (finish): returning to refs/heads/new-catalog-demo
c3f9338 HEAD@{2}: rebase (pick): Add feature 2
5ddb34c HEAD@{3}: rebase (pick): Add feature 1
ed804d5 HEAD@{8}: commit: Add feature 2
5c91e3d HEAD@{9}: commit: Add feature 1
fb90356 HEAD@{10}: checkout: moving from master to new-catalog-demo
fb90356 HEAD@{11}: reset: moving to fb90356
b4bf1c6 (origin/master, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{12}: clone: from https://github.com/itsjoshthedeveloper/git-practice.git
```

I spot the last good commit on `new-catalog-demo` is `ed804d5`, so i reset to this point.

```
u@d git-practice]$ git reset --hard ed804d5
HEAD wskazuje teraz ed804d5 Add feature 2
```

Now i have my `new-catalog-demo` branch with my ole changes before i rebased it on outage master

```
[u@d git-practice]$ git log --oneline --graph 
* c3f9338 (HEAD -> new-catalog-demo) Add feature 2
* 5ddb34c Add feature 1
* b89ef1b (master) Change another feature
```

No we can release it onto origin/master to be sure we do it on the current state of master branch.

```
[u@d git-practice]$ git rebase origin/master 
Pomyślnie przestawiono i zaktualizowano refs/heads/new-catalog-demo.
[u@d git-practice]$ git log --oneline --graph 
* 86a2a81 (HEAD -> new-catalog-demo) Add feature 2
* 3dca49f Add feature 1
* b4bf1c6 (origin/master, origin/HEAD) Update main feature
* f716c02 Change another main feature
```

At last we can merge `new-catalog-demo` to local master.

```
[u@d git-practice]$ git checkout master 
Przełączono na gałąź „master”
Twoja gałąź jest za „origin/master” o 4 zapisy i może zostać przewinięta.
  (użyj „git pull”, aby zaktualizować lokalną gałąź)
[u@d git-practice]$ git merge new-catalog-demo 
Aktualizowanie b89ef1b..86a2a81
Fast-forward
 README.md      | 5 ++++-
 web/index.html | 2 +-
 2 files changed, 5 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
[u@d git-practice]$ git log --oneline --graph 
* 86a2a81 (HEAD -> master, new-catalog-demo) Add feature 2
* 3dca49f Add feature 1
* b4bf1c6 (origin/master, origin/HEAD) Update main feature
* f716c02 Change another main feature
* f4f9669 Change main feature
* 98acbf4 Reset changed features
* b89ef1b Change another feature
* e7278df Change a main feature
* fb90356 Add JavaScript
* a0f3d5a Add another main feature
* 5a7b447 Add main feature
* ec699c4 Update README
* 395a5c6 Add h1
* e1633b3 Add index.html
* f11b51f Initial commit
```

Now history is clean, and we haven't missed any changes and there is no duplicate commits. I hope now You see how to use `git reflog` to fixed this kind of issue.

Comment: I appreciate the long answer, but I think there is some misunderstanding with what my problem is. I rebased `new-catalog` with the outdated local `master` and pulled into the new rebased `origin/new-catalog` branch. So, `A'` is the rebased _**set**_ of commits which are a duplicate of `A` which is the original _**set**_ of commits on the `new-catalog` branch. In your case, `A` would be commits `5c91e3d` and `ed804d5`. Your answer also does not take into account the second set of commits `B` which were added to the `beta/master` branch after rebasing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "weird conflicts", it is just the effect of a rebase. The duplicated commits are not even taken into consideration because already merged into the `beta/master` branch. As you noticed, your repository is a bit messy, but you can still easily (probably not quickly) reach the desired state. The problem is that you waited too long before merging your changes into `master`, with the side effect of redundant commits: apart from the duplicated `new-catalog` branch, the merged pull request commit is in practice a fast-forward from `new-catalog`. You can verify it yourself that you have multiple commits with the same tree: I am talking about

```
| * ec73ee6 Merge pull request #4 from itsjoshthedeveloper/new-catalog
|/| 
| *   84aabf5 Merge branch 'new-catalog' of https://github.com/itsjoshthedeveloper/git-practice into new-catalog
| |\  
| | * b40f340 Add a new JS feature
| | ...
| | ...
| | ...
| * | 4b463f5 Add a new JS feature
```

Just to clear any doubt, you can easily find which is the common root from where the rebase process starts using `git log $(git merge-base master beta/master) -n 1 --format="%h %s"`, which returns

```
f4f9669 Change main feature
```

The conflicts arisen when you rebase `beta/master` on `master` comes from the changes you have done throughout the `beta/master` branch on `web/index.html`. This last file has been changed in the original `master` too, this is the reason of your conflicts, not the duplicated `new-catalog`. So, what to do in general?
Here is the dilemma: `git merge` takes the tips of your branches and the nearest common root, it tries to merge them together and create a commit (unless `--no-commit` specified), unless no conflict present, "simple" as that. On the other hand, with `git rebase` you could have many more conflicts to solve along the way, caused by the projection (`cherry-pick`) of each commit starting from a new base, but ending up with a linear history. I suggest you to choose the second approach only when you frequently integrate your changes, in order to avoid conflicts between multiple branches as much as possible.

---

Regarding the `beta/bootstrap` branch, looking at the changes you made there, a rebase on `beta/master` or on `master` should not create any conflicts. However, it is definitely more convenient for you to rebase `beta/bootstrap` on `beta/master` first, then rebase (or do a merge before) `beta/bootstrap` on `master`. In this way, with a single rebase you bring both of their tips forward.

Consider even the use of [`rerere`](https://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rerere): it seems like you are in a difficult situation because you have too many conflicts to tackle. `git rerere` is a very interesting functionality that consists on caching how you solve a certain conflict. Suppose you completed a merge, but in the end you decide you want to do a rebase and restart from zero: some conflicts are automatically solved because they are the same encountered earlier.

---

**EDIT:**
From comments:

> I tried rebasing `beta/bootstrap` on `beta/master` first, but after I rebased `beta/master` on `master`, I had to rebase `beta/bootstrap` on `beta/master` again

Sure you had, you can only rebase one branch per time, even if they do share most of their history. To avoid the `rebase --onto`, you could have rebased `beta/bootstrap` on `beta/master` and next `beta/bootstrap` on `master`. At this point the `beta/bootstrap` branch has both `master` branch and `beta/master` commit as its ancestors. To move `beta/master` branch to the new commit on `master` mainline, you have to force it with something like `git branch -f beta/master beta/bootstrap~2`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I'm glad that the duplicated commits don't directly cause any of the conflicts. However, I am still confused on what exactly I need to do to resolve this situation.

Comment: You don't have many options other than solving all conflicts from the start of your branch (with a rebase), or from the tip of your branch (with a merge). The point of my answer is that you should integrate your changes on `master` as soon as possible, considering that rebasing a long branch like that one might take some time and it is very error-prone. Personally, I would do a merge and forget about all that mess. Lucky for you if someone comes out with an elegant solution, but I find it very unlikely given that you don't want to "*lose the time information of those commits*".

Comment: Even if it is possible to simplify your history, in a way compliant to your requests, those conflicts won't be solved by themselves (as far as I know :) ). As I said, depending on the changes throughout the history, `rerere` feature might help you.

Comment: Yup, I'll make sure to rebase often from now on. I found a way how to do it with rebasing. Also, I found out rebase actually saves the author timestamp and only replaces the commit timestamp which is fine for me.

Comment: Although you don't fully answer my question, I think that your answer was helpful!

Comment: @josh I just saw your solution and I am happy for you that you made it :) rebase onto is a very powerful feature of git for history rewriting. Even so, I don't believe it was necessary if you had rebased `beta/bootstrap` on `beta/master` first, and then updated the branch pointers. Anyway, glad you solved (and thanks for the bounty!).

Comment: I tried rebasing `beta/bootstrap` on `beta/master` first, but after I rebased `beta/master` on `master`, I had to rebase `beta/bootstrap` on `beta/master` again

Comment: @josh sorry I explained myself poorly, see the edit please.